# postgresql - determine schema from table name

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6

I have multiple schemas each containing a table with the same name "t".

How do I find out what schema "select * from t" is evaluated in ?

Example:

```
create schema one;
create schema two;
create schema three;
create table one.t(i int);
create table two.t(i int);

set search_path to one,two;
select magic_function('t');  -- returns 'one'

set search_path to two,one;
select magic_function('t');  -- returns 'two'

set search_path to three,two,one;
select magic_function('t');  -- returns 'two'
```

What is "magic_function" in this case ?

Comment: Think hard about the value of being explict. `select * from one.t` removes all doubt, and it's robust in the face of search path changes. I usually just use the search path for third-party stuff like GIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need `fn()` here - just [plain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) select:

```
t=# set search_path to one,two;
SET
t=# select relname, relnamespace::regnamespace from pg_class where oid = 't'::regclass;
 relname | relnamespace
---------+--------------
 t       | one
(1 row)

t=# set search_path to two,one;
SET
t=# select relname, relnamespace::regnamespace from pg_class where oid = 't'::regclass;
 relname | relnamespace
---------+--------------
 t       | two
(1 row)
```

of course it's wrappable if you demand

Comment: Perfect.  That is exactly what I am looking for.